# requesting help making sub-class(es) access main class in python

Tags: python

Hello I am looking for a way to make it so class A could have sub-class B and `self` in sub-class B points to A
Example of what i am trying to do

```py
class A:
    value = 'asdf'
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = self.B()
    
    class B:
        def printa(self):
            print(self.val)

aa = A()
aa.B.printa()
```

so in this example the function would print `asdf`

Comment: There *are no subclasses in your code*

Comment: Please select Tim's answer. Mine is nearly identical, and emphasizes a neat trick you did unintentionally. Please don't actually use it as it will shoot you in the foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about being embedded.  If you want the inner class to access the parent values, then you need to give it the parent.  By the way, you can't have `self.B` be both a class and an object.

```
class A:
    value = 'asdf'
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.B(self)
    
    class B:
        def __init__(self,parent):
            self.parent = parent
        def printa(self):
            print(self.parent.value)

aa = A()
aa.b.printa()
```

Comment: Yes you can, but only once. The first access will look up in the class, then the instance variable will shadow all further lookups

Comment: Technically, it can't be both.  It's either on or the other.  However, that's not what he wants, given the signature for `B.printa`.

Comment: It's exactly what he wants. self.B is a reference to the class before the assignment, and an instance immediately after, but only for that instance of A. I'm not saying it's a good idea, just that it happens to work out

Answer (score 0):

As [@Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69320763/2988730) correctly pointed out, nested classes are not special in python. They bear no connection whatsoever to the enclosing class (and in fact are created before it even exists). You need to pass the parent to the nested class.

The nice thing is that your assignment `self.B = self.B()` works out in a probably unintentional manner. What happens is that `self.B()` looks for `B` in the instance `__dict__`, doesn't find it, and therefore looks it up in the class. The call to `B()` happens on the nested class `B`. The resulting instance is immediately assigned, so that `self.B` is not an instance of `B` going forward. This is not pretty and extremely error prone, but I think it's neat.

The simplest thing to do is to give `B` an initializer that can record the parent:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value='asdf'):
        self.B = self.B(self)
    
    class B:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def printa(self):
            print(self.parent.value)

aa = A()
aa.B.printa()
```

The biggest problem is of course that `A.B` and `aa.B` are two totally different things.